# How to pass multiple variable from typescript (angular.js) to Controller in Web API(MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass two parameter from typescript with angular.js to Controller. i tried this way but it didn't work. accutually i don't know that the way of i pass this parameters are correct

```
 IncrementDonation(donationId: number, donationAmount: number, successCallback: Function): void {
    this.httpService.put("/API/PrivateAPI/MyGivingPortfolio?donationId=" + donationId + "&donationAmount=" + donationAmount).success(function () {
        successCallback();
    });

}
```

values of donation Id and donation amount is passed from view.

This is my controller code.

```
 public bool Update(int donationId, decimal donationAmount)
    {
       // Some Code goes here

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing Controller Code like this it works fine. Thanks.. :D

```
public bool Put(int donationId, decimal donationAmount)
{
   // Some Code goes here

}
```

Comment: +1 but will give my answer below, as this is surely a coincidence that this works

Answer (score 1):

Krishan,

I've noticed that you managed to get this working by using a method called `Put`. I have to confess (without trying), I cannot see how this will work as you reference a method called `MyGivingPortfolio` from your angular code. The method signature should (imho) be (notice i also qualify the http request type as `[HttpPut]`):

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult MyGivingPortfolio(int donationId, decimal donationAmount)
{
    // Some Code goes here
    // return appropriate json back to angular
}
```

Worth noting this as an alternative, in case you just lucked out with your approach above.

Comment: He is using webapi not mvc. He has incorrectly tagged the question. :)

Comment: ahhh - i see, tho i'm certain that my observation on the methodname holds true

Comment: BASarat Is Correct. :D